# Duda HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, web

les vengo con una duda

Me preguntaba cómo podría hacer para que en la siguiente web hubiera el mismo espacio entre PJ  PG  PE  PP  GF  GC y el borde derecho, esto es, que fuera proporcional como ya están pero que el GC también quede como el resto, ya que como podréis comprobar su espacio es más pequeño y quiero que quede proporcional. Lo siento por la destreza de mi código pero soy bastante novato y este proyecto lo llevo a cabo precisamente para aprender. Si no entendéis a lo que me refiero (es probable), responded y sin problema intento especificar lo máximo posible. Espero que no sea mucha molestia.

Muchas gracias!!

```css
*{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
   font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }

/* Michu DB */

#laliga {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}

.clasificacion {
   background-color: rgb(37, 40, 42);
   box-sizing: content-box;
   width: 80%;
   margin: auto;
   margin-bottom: 80px;
   border-top: 4px outset rgb(146, 218, 236);
   padding: 12px;
   font-family: 'Raleway', 'Trebuchet MS';
}

.equipo-box {
   background-color: white;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-top: 2px outset rgb(146, 218, 236);
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto; 
   display: table;
   padding: 24px;
}

.encabezado-clasif {
   background-color: rgb(146, 218, 236);
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 22px;
   display: table;
}

.posicion {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 4px;
   padding-right: 12px;
   width: 10%;
   min-width: 45px;
   text-align: center;
}

.equipo {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 4px;
   width: 40%;
}

.puntos {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 4px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   width: 7.5%;
   min-width: 30px;
   text-align: center;
}

.partidos-jugados {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 7.5%;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.partidos-empatados {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 7.5%;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.partidos-ganados {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 7.5%;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.partidos-perdidos {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 7.5%;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.goles-favor {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 7.5%;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.goles-contra {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 7.5%;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.encabezado-txt {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgb(37, 40, 42);
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.equipo img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img src="img/michudb/laliga.png" id="laliga">
    <div class="clasificacion">
        <div class="encabezado-clasif">
            <div class="posicion">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">POSICIÓN</p>
            </div>
            <div class="equipo">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">EQUIPO</p>
            </div>
            <div class="puntos">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">PUNTOS</p>
            </div>
            <div class="partidos-jugados">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">PJ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="partidos-ganados">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">PG</p>
            </div>
            <div class="partidos-empatados">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">PE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="partidos-perdidos">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">PP</p>
            </div>
            <div class="goles-favor">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">GF</p>
            </div>
            <div class="goles-contra">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">GC</p>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="equipo-box">
            <div class="posicion">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="equipo">
                <img src="img/michudb/fcbarcelona.png">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">FC BARCELONA</p>
            </div>
            <div class="puntos">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">58</p>
            </div>
            <div class="partidos-jugados">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">20</p>
            </div>
            <div class="partidos-ganados">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">17</p>
            </div>
            <div class="partidos-empatados">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="partidos-perdidos">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="goles-favor">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">98</p>
            </div>
            <div class="goles-contra">
                <p class="encabezado-txt">21</p>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Disculpa pero no veo ni entiendo el problema, si pudieras editar y explicar mejor tu duda sería mas fácil ayudar

Comment: Hola! El problema es que la distancia que hay entre los nombre PJ, PG, PE, PP... no son proporcionales al espacio que hay por ejemplo entre el GC y el borde derecho... quiero que todos los PG, PE, PP, GA, GC etc. ocupen el mismo espacio y haya el mismo espacio entre ellos y el valor anteior/próximo... ahora mejor?

Comment: Si @Unai dame unos minutos para poder plantearte una respuesta

Comment: Perfecto @BetaM , gracias!